# Textfield is not formatted once populated with data

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, format, uitextfield

I have a textfield for numbers that is already formatted when user types in the field; it would look like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

phoneNumberTextField.delegate = self
retrieveUserData()

}

    func formattedNumber(number: String) -> String {
        let cleanPhoneNumber = number.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined()
        let mask = "(XXX) XXX-XXXX"

        var result = ""
        var index = cleanPhoneNumber.startIndex
        for ch in mask where index < cleanPhoneNumber.endIndex {
            if ch == "X" {
                result.append(cleanPhoneNumber[index])
                index = cleanPhoneNumber.index(after: index)
            } else {
                result.append(ch)
            }
        }
        return result
    }



extension AccounInfotVC: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let text = textField.text else { return false }
        let newString = (text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        textField.text = formattedNumber(number: newString)
        return false
    }
}
```

However, when my view loads; the number is not formatted once its auto populated from the database with this code:

```
func retrieveUserData(){


        db.collection(DatabaseRef.Users).document(userID).getDocument { (snap, error) in
            self.phoneNumberTextField?.text = phoneNumber

    }
}
```

so the number gets populated like this: 
[image]

instead of this: [image]

Any idea how i can get it to populate the textfield in the same format as when user types?

Note that, when I save the phone number, I remove spaces and the characters so number is saved like `1234567889` in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
self.phoneNumberTextField?.text = phoneNumber
```

won't trigger `shouldChangeCharactersIn` , you need

```
self.phoneNumberTextField?.text = formattedNumber(number:phoneNumber)
```

Comment: How do I get it to trigger it?

Comment: Do you know how I can change this code so I can format a Canadian postal code instead?  e.g. M9C 1L2 (3 numbers, 3 letters, and one space)